# Linear Approximation 2

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Use a linear approximation of $$f(x) = \sqrt[3]{x}$$ at $$x=8$$ to approximate $$\sqrt[3]{7}$$.

Express your answer as an exact fraction.

Comment: Not marked as homework?! Anyway, reveal your attempts (besides copying your homework here) in finding that fraction first, please.

Answer (score 1):

$$f'(x_0)\approx\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}$$
$$\Rightarrow f(x_0+h)\approx f'(x_0)h+f(x_0)$$
Take $h=-1$ and $x_0=8$
$$f(7)\approx f'(8)(-1)+f(8)\approx-\frac{1}{12}+2\approx\frac{23}{12}$$

Comment: Cui bono? Certainly not the original poster.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\sqrt[3]{7\,} = \sqrt[3]{8 - 1} = 2\,\sqrt[3]{1 - {1 \over 8}}
\approx
2\left(1 - {1 \over 3}\,{1 \over 8}\right)
=
2\,{23 \over 24} = {23 \over 12} \approx 1.91666666666667
$$

Error $= 0.5870\ \%$